# Geotools java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, geotools

I am attempting to write some simple GeoTools based code for accessing a WFS server.  The code looks like this so far:

```
        String getCapabilities = "http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/survey/pgb_survey/dev/OGC_services/ndfdOWSserver.php?SERVICE=WFS&Request=GetCapabilities";
        Map<String, String> connectionParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities);
        WFSDataStoreFactory  dsf = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
        try {
            WFSDataStore dataStore = dsf.createDataStore(connectionParameters);
            String types[] = dataStore.getTypeNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(types[i]);
            }
            SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("ndfd:Forecast_Gml2Point");
            SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures();
            while(fc.features().hasNext()){
                SimpleFeature sf = fc.features().next();
                System.out.println(sf.getAttribute("myname"));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

This works up until the line with the call to getFeatures() at which point I get the dreaded java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hsqldb.lib.FrameworkLogger
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getEventLogger(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getEventLogger(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.logInfoEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.closePersistence(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
[...]
at org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.WFS_1_0_0_DataStore.getSchema(WFS_1_0_0_DataStore.java:386)
at org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.WFSFeatureSource.getSchema(WFSFeatureSource.java:207)
at org.geotools.data.wfs.v1_0_0.WFSFeatureSource.getFeatures(WFSFeatureSource.java:231)
at wfsClient.WfsClient.main(WfsClient.java:100)
```

Reading similar problems (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629118/geotools-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-driving-me-crazy)) suggests that hsqldb is missing from the classpath -- but it is not.  I have followed the directions on [this page](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html) to download the GeoTools archive and add all the Jars to my Eclipse project.  (I cannot use Maven as the Eclipse Maven plugin doesn't play nicely with our proxy.)  I have deleted all the suggested conflicting Jars, as well as the ones suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429097/geotools-cannot-find-hsql-epsg-db-throws-error-nosuchauthoritycodeexception).  I have checked the classpath on my code and it includes the "GeoTools Download" project with all of the Jars exported. (I have also added all the jars explicitly to my classpath and get the same error.)

If I dump my project to a Ant build file, this is what the path definition looks like:

```
<path id="GeoTools Download.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/bin"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/ant-1.8.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/batik-transcoder-1.7.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/bridj-0.6-c-only.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/bufr-4.3.16.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/common-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-cli-2.0-gt2-pre1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-codec-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-digester-1.7.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-io-2.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-jxpath-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/core.commands-3.6.0.I20100512-1500.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/core.runtime-3.6.0.v20100505.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/eastwood-1.1.1-20090908.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/ecore-2.6.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/ehcache-1.6.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/equinox.common-3.6.0.v20100503.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gdal-1.8.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/geodb-0.7-RC2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/grib-4.3.16.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-api-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-app-schema-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-app-schema-resolver-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-arcgrid-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-brewer-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-charts-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-complex-13-RC1-tests.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-complex-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-coverage-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-coverage-api-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-coveragetools-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-cql-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-css-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-csv-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-data-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-epsg-hsql-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-feature-aggregate-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-feature-pregeneralized-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-geojson-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-geometry-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-geopkg-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-geotiff-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-graph-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-grassraster-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-grib-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-grid-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-gtopo30-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-image-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-imageio-ext-gdal-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-imagemosaic-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-imagepyramid-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-jdbc-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-jp2k-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-jts-wrapper-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-main-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-matfile5-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-mbtiles-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-metadata-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-mongodb-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-netcdf-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-ogr-bridj-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-ogr-core-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-ogr-jni-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-opengis-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-process-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-process-feature-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-process-geometry-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-process-raster-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-property-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-property-old-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-referencing-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-referencing3D-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-render-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-sample-data-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-sample-data-access-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-sfs-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-shapefile-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-solr-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-svg-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-swing-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-swt-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-transform-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-validation-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-vpf-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-wfs-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-wfs-ng-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-wms-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-wps-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xml-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-core-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-csw-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-fes-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-filter-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-gml2-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-gml3-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-kml-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-ows-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-sld-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-wcs-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-wfs-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-wms-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/gt-xsd-wps-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/h2-1.1.119.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/hsqldb-2.2.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/icu4j-3.4.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-arcgrid-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalarcbinarygrid-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdaldted-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalecw-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalecwjp2-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalehdr-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalenvihdr-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalerdasimg-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalidrisi-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalkakadujp2-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalmrsid-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalmrsidjp2-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalnitf-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-gdalrpftoc-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-geocore-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-imagereadmt-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-imagereadmt-1.1M012010.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-kakadu-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-mat-sas-1.1M012010.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-streams-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-tiff-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/imageio-ext-utilities-1.1.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jai_codec-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jai_imageio-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/javacsv-2.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jdom-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jface-3.6.1.M20100825-0800.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jgridshift-1.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/json-simple-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jsqlparser-0.3.14.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jt-contour-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jt-rangelookup-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jt-utils-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jt-vectorbinarize-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jt-vectorize-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jt-zonalstats-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/jts-1.13.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/miglayout-3.7-swing.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/mongo-java-driver-2.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/net.opengis.csw-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/net.opengis.fes-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/net.opengis.ows-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/net.opengis.wcs-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/net.opengis.wfs-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/net.opengis.wps-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/netcdf-4.3.16.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/opendap-2.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/org.w3.xlink-13-RC1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/parboiled-java-1.1.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/picocontainer-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/solr-solrj-4.9.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/spatialite-jdbc-3.7.2-2.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/swt.gtk.linux.x86-3.6.1.v3655c.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/swt.win32.win32.x86_64-3.6.1.v3655c.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/ui.workbench-3.6.1.M20100826-1330.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/vecmath-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/xml-commons-resolver-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/xpp3-1.1.3.4.O.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/xsd-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${GeoTools Download.location}/geotools-13-RC1/slf4j-log4j-1.6.4.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="WFS Client Project.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <path refid="GeoTools Download.classpath"/>
</path>
```

You'll see there's just the one epsg jar file in there, and just the one jdbc jar.  I have done the same thing with version 12.2 with the same results.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?  Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can't really help as we really don't support building without maven, but you are missing an hsqldb dependency rather than a geotools one.

Comment: What dependency?  I have hsqldb-2.2.8.jar in my path.  (I can't build with maven because this machine is offline.)

Comment: There are probably jars that hsqldb is dependent on, try building on a connected machine to ser

Comment: Hsqldb does not appear to depend upon any jars.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem using maven. I think the only sure way to resolve this is to build your project using mvn on an online machine and then copy over the required dependencies. Or if you really must continue the way you are then try removing jars one at a time to see which one is causing the problem.

**EDIT**

I can reproduce the error following the outdated steps in the Quickstart, The best guess I can find is [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/f3692a67) which suggests there is a logging problem. This does seem plausible as it is trying to throw a SAX error when the issue comes up.

If you remove all the other jars (that are not in my list below) it will work.

However the GeoTools logging code is a complex place that I fear to tread, so try adding log4j or switch to using epsg-wkt as that also fixes the issue.

If it helps here is what Maven thinks you should need as dependencies:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:list (default-cli) @ artifactid ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO]    it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-tiff:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO]    it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-utilities:jar:1.1.10:compile
[INFO]    java3d:vecmath:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    javax.media:jai_imageio:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    jgridshift:jgridshift:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    net.java.dev.jsr-275:jsr-275:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.xml:xml-commons-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO]    org.eclipse.xsd:xsd:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-api:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-coverage:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-cql:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-data:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-graph:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-main:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-wfs-ng:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-xml:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.fes:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.ows:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.wfs:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.ogc:org.w3.xlink:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-core:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-fes:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-filter:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-gml2:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-gml3:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-ows:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools.xsd:gt-xsd-wfs:jar:13-RC1:compile
[INFO]    org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.8:compile
[INFO]    org.jaitools:jt-utils:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.jaitools:jt-zonalstats:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the effort you're putting into helping.  I really appreciate it.  Checking against that list of dependencies, they are all on my buildpath except for xml-apis.jar.  I found that and added it, but that did not resolve the error.  (BTW, all of those jars are included in GeoTools except for the xml-apis.jar.  Does that need to be added to the distribution?)

Comment: As far as not using Maven, I am following the instructions on the [Quickstart page for Eclipse](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html) under "Download GeoTools".  If you have time, can you try that and see if you get the same error I'm seeing?