# No code "EPSG:4326" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS"

Tags: java, maven, geotools

I am trying to GeoTool's CoordinateReferenceSystem with the following code:

```
try {
    targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    logger.info("\nTarget: " + targetCRS.toWKT());
} catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
    logger.error(e.toString());
} catch (FactoryException e) {
    logger.error(e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.toString());
}
```

It works when I run the service in vscode, but when I deploy it to Kubernetes, I get:

> 2020-03-31 20:54:16,985 ERROR (TrackRecordProjector.java:76) -
>   org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code
>   "EPSG:4326" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type
>   "EngineeringCRS".

I assume this is something to do with the HSQL database that contains the reference systems.

I checked my JAR that is produced using:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The META-INF/services folder in the JAR contains two different entries for org.opengis.referencing.cs.CSAuthorityFactory. I checked based on a comment on this site for another question ([Geotools cannot find HSQL EPSG DB, throws error: NoSuchAuthorityCodeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429097/geotools-cannot-find-hsql-epsg-db-throws-error-nosuchauthoritycodeexception)). However I don't know what this means and how to fix it.

Comment: use Maven Shade plugin instead of assemble - see https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was being stubborn sticking with the assembly plugin, but I think you're both right that I need to switch to the shade plugin.

Comment: there is no way to make the assembly plugin do it as it doesn't understand how to combine the spi files