# Geotools: Getting IllegalArgumentException: Argument "ellipsoid" should not be null after "org.opengis.referncing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException" error

Tags: java, maven, coordinate-systems, geotools, maven-shade-plugin

I encountered the common `"org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:4326" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS"` while trying to run my packaged jar on an Apache Flink cluster.

I already had `gt-epsg-hsql` added as a dependency when I got the above error. I managed to fix that by following the instructions [on the official Geotools building FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app) and rearranging the dependency order in my pom.xml file and using [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

But it seems now I encounter a new exception which is this one.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "ellipsoid" should not be null.
    at org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator.<init>(GeodeticCalculator.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator.<init>(GeodeticCalculator.java:188) ~[?:?]
```

Spent the whole day pulling my hair trying to debug this but had no success. It all works when running it on a local cluster via my IDE but packaging and deploying the jar to my cluster causes these errors.

I tried emulating the suggested POM that the original asker had listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429097/geotools-cannot-find-hsql-epsg-db-throws-error-nosuchauthoritycodeexception) and modified my pom.xml file to the current one attached below but it still gives the same error. Incase anyone needs to see my full pom.xml for details, [it is hosted here on Textbin.](https://textbin.net/erewuvb7ud)

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- GeoTools Related -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

```
    <plugins>
                <!-- Java Compiler -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
                <!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
                <!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactSet>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                        <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </artifactSet>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                        Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>DataGen.StreamingJob</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                    <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files         -->
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

EDIT: Apache Flink version 1.13.0. Geotools 28-SNAPSHOT. Java version "1.8.0_333".
Adding the contents of `META-INF/services`:

```
├── com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
├── com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec
├── it.geosolutions.imageio.compression.CompressorSpi
├── it.geosolutions.imageio.compression.DecompressorSpi
├── java.sql.Driver
├── javax.annotation.processing.Processor
├── javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider
├── javax.imageio.spi.ImageInputStreamSpi
├── javax.imageio.spi.ImageOutputStreamSpi
├── javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
├── javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi
├── javax.measure.spi.FormatService
├── javax.measure.spi.ServiceProvider
├── javax.measure.spi.SystemOfUnitsService
├── javax.measure.spi.UnitFormatService
├── javax.media.jai.OperationRegistrySpi
├── javax.media.jai.OperationsRegistrySpi
├── javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
├── org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientFactory
├── org.apache.flink.core.execution.PipelineExecutorFactory
├── org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.SecurityContextFactory
├── org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.SecurityModuleFactory
├── org.apache.flink.runtime.state.changelog.StateChangelogWriterFactory
├── org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
├── org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec
├── org.apache.flink.table.factories.Factory
├── org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactory
├── org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.ConfigProvider
├── org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ContextDataProvider
├── org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ThreadDumpMessage$ThreadInfoFactory
├── org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.Provider
├── org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource
├── org.geotools.coverage.grid.GridCoverageFactory
├── org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.footprint.FootprintLoaderSpi
├── org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi
├── org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFactorySpi
├── org.geotools.feature.AttributeTypeFactory
├── org.geotools.filter.FunctionExpression
├── org.geotools.filter.FunctionFactory
├── org.geotools.filter.expression.PropertyAccessorFactory
├── org.geotools.http.HTTPClientFactory
├── org.geotools.referencing.factory.gridshift.GridShiftLocator
├── org.geotools.referencing.operation.MathTransformProvider
├── org.geotools.renderer.crs.ProjectionHandlerFactory
├── org.geotools.renderer.style.ExternalGraphicFactory
├── org.geotools.renderer.style.MarkFactory
├── org.geotools.styling.StyleFactory
├── org.geotools.swing.tool.InfoToolHelper
├── org.geotools.util.ConverterFactory
├── org.jaitools.numeric.Processor
├── org.jboss.marshalling.ProviderDescriptor
├── org.opengis.coverage.processing.Operation
├── org.opengis.feature.FeatureFactory
├── org.opengis.feature.type.FeatureTypeFactory
├── org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory
├── org.opengis.filter.expression.Function
├── org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.cs.CSAuthorityFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.cs.CSFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.datum.DatumAuthorityFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.datum.DatumFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.operation.CoordinateOperationAuthorityFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.operation.CoordinateOperationFactory
├── org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransformFactory
├── reactor.blockhound.integration.BlockHoundIntegration
└── tech.units.indriya.spi.NumberSystem

1 directory, 67 files
```

Comment: can you check what is in the `META-INF/services` file in the output and add it to your question

Comment: Technically java 8 is no longer supported by GeoTools at 28.x so may be try with 11 and see if that helps?

Comment: @IanTurton So I tried upgrading to 11. Still get the same error unfortunately. Also tried using geotools version 24.5, but same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the problem has nothing to do with Geotools.

The problem was in these specific lines of the my code:

```
crs = Params.coordinateReferenceSystem;
GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
```

and the `crs` was being set to null because `Params.coordinateReferenceSystem` was defined as a static variable. Static variables cannot be serialized hence are not replicated across all nodes in a distributed system.

The result of which it works perfectly on the local IDE but fails on the cluster.